# Pulumi code to add own vpc to ec2 instance

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

Hi I am trying to create an ec2 instance by attaching the vpc to it but I am not able to create instance

```ts
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

const myVpc = new aws.ec2.Vpc("myVpc", {
  cidrBlock: "172.16.0.0/16",
  tags: {
    Name: "Darshan",
  },
});

const mySubnet = new aws.ec2.Subnet("mySubnet", {
  vpcId: myVpc.id,
  cidrBlock: "172.16.10.0/24",
  availabilityZone: "us-west-2a",
  tags: {
    Name: "Darshan",  
    },
});

const NetworkInterface = new aws.ec2.NetworkInterface("NetworkInterface", {
    subnetId: mySubnet.id,
    privateIps: ["172.16.10.100"],
    tags: {
        Name: "primary_network_interface",
    },
});

const Instance = new aws.ec2.Instance("Instance", {
    ami: "ami-020ae06fdda6a0f66",
    instanceType: "t2.micro",
    networkInterfaces: [{
        networkInterfaceId: NetworkInterface.id,
        deviceIndex: 0,
    }],
    creditSpecification: {
        cpuCredits: "unlimited",
    },
});
```

Comment: Please extend your questions to explain the problem that you are facing including any error messages

Comment: Mikhail Shilkov 
I am not getting any error but the instance is not be creating.
or else do I need to make any changes to the code? because in all pulumi script they have given only with respect to instance creation but I need to create an instance and attach that instance to vpc

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to launch it.

#1. Use a t3.micro vs t2.micro.  The t3's are cheaper, have more memory, and more cpu, and more network bandwidth. You can compare it over here:  https://instances.vantage.sh/?region=us-west-2.  This means you can drop this:  `creditSpecification`

#2. The ami:  `ami-020ae06fdda6a0f66` only exist in us-east-2(ohio).  This ami is `aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2018.03.0.x86_64-tomcat8.5java8-hvm-201906160916` looks like it is from the following [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) and they are launching it in us-east-2. So switch to us-east-2(ohio) to launch it. Otherwise, you will need to pick another ami that exist in us-west-2.

#3.  The following code works in us-east-2 with the ami from above.

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

const myVpc = new aws.ec2.Vpc("demo-myVpc", {
    cidrBlock: "172.16.0.0/16",
    tags: {
      Name: "Darshan",
    },
  });

  const mySubnet = new aws.ec2.Subnet("demo-mySubnet", {
    vpcId: myVpc.id,
    cidrBlock: "172.16.10.0/24",
    availabilityZone: "us-east-2a",
    tags: {
      Name: "Darshan",  
      },
  });

  const Instance = new aws.ec2.Instance("demo-Instance", {
    ami: "ami-020ae06fdda6a0f66",
    instanceType: "t3.micro",
    subnetId: mySubnet.id,
  });

  export const my_vpc = myVpc.id;
  export const my_vpc_cidr_block = myVpc.cidrBlock;
  export const my_vpc_cidr_tags = myVpc.tags;
  export const my_subnet = mySubnet.id;
  export const my_subnet_cidr_block = mySubnet.cidrBlock;
  export const my_subnet_tags = mySubnet.tags;
  export const my_instance_ami = Instance.ami;
  export const my_instance_id = Instance.id;
```

To view the [outputs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_stack_output/) run: `pulumi stack output`

```
Current stack outputs (8):
    OUTPUT                VALUE
    my_instance_ami       ami-020ae06fdda6a0f66
    my_instance_id        i-02310475c052c8097
    my_subnet             subnet-0e8141c37b149ea77
    my_subnet_cidr_block  172.16.10.0/24
    my_subnet_tags        {"Name":"Darshan"}
    my_vpc                vpc-00eab339e95459c27
    my_vpc_cidr_block     172.16.0.0/16
    my_vpc_cidr_tags      {"Name":"Darshan"}
```